# Unable to send object value in next request json body

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I am trying to send object value based on condition to the previous request.
[image]
From above,pricecheck i will get formtype value based on form type validation i have to send guests info in request..
here i am able to validate but not able to pass the object value if i try any string i can able to do,please help me.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a string value in vars, surrounded with quotes `"` and escape inner quotes`\"`,as

```
 vars.put("guests", "{ \"title\":\"Mr\", ....  }");
```

Comment: thanks,i tried above and not working now even not reading the value using below ```vars.put("guests","{
                    \"title\": \"Mr\",
                    \"first_name\": \"testing\",
                    \"last_name\": \"paxone\",
                    \"age\": 34,
                    \"type\": \"adult\",
                    \"nationality\": \"IN\"
                }")}```

Comment: @SinuReddy the end should be `"IN\" }");`

Comment: Stll same, ```vars.put("guests","{
                    \"title\": \"Mr\",
                    \"first_name\": \"testing\",
                    \"last_name\": \"paxone\",
                    \"age\": 34,
                    \"type\": \"adult\",
                    \"nationality\": "IN\"
                }");}```   I am not sure i am missing anything,can you advise?

Answer (score 0):

You're violating 2 major best practices:

1. You're referring [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like `${form}` in the [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) while you should be using `vars.get('form')` construction instead
2. You're using JavaScript language which is a performance anti-pattern, since JMeter 3.1 you should be using [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for scripting

Check out [Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html) article to learn more about reading and generating JSON in Groovy.

Also [posting code in form of screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) is not something you should be doing otherwise the chance of getting a comprehensive answer will be much less

Comment: Dmitri -Thanks but seems i am asking something and you giving some different,i am not worry about parsing my issue is post parsing based on validation need to send the object variable(which is not from the previous request) in next request

Comment: I'm telling that you're doing this wrong and giving you direction regarding how to do this right. And if you provide 2 JSON objects instead of screenshots, the one you have and the one you want to get most probably me or someone else will help you with the Groovy code

Comment: Dmitri,sure..My result is below from previous response.```{ "meta": {"request": {"rate_id": "U2FsdGVkX19"  },  "form_type": 2 }``` so from this i extracted formtype using json extractor and stored in form,now my  script to validate formtype and based on formtype sending guests value```var formData = JSON.parse(vars.get("form"));
var formtype = formData.formtype;

if(formtype == 2) {
    vars.put("guests", "({"title": "Mr","first_name": "testing","last_name": "paxone","age": 34,"type":"adult","nationality": "IN"})");}``` and pass guests value in next request

Comment: Next request body :```{
  "prebook_id": "${requestid}",
  "source_id": "${sourceid}",
  "adults_count": 1,
  "child_count": 0,
  "child_ages": [],
  "rooms_count": 1,
  "guests":${guests}
}``` hope got my question now,please advise